# how to manage Date interval in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new in Hive-Hadoop. I have some problem with Date interval management.

In Postgresql, I can get the "6 days" before a given date :

```
select max(datejour) + INTERVAL '-6 day' as maxdate from table
```

e.g : if max(datejour) = 2015-08-22  ==> my query returns  2015-08-15

Does somebody can help me on how could I do it in Hive?

thanks.

Comment: Should it return  2015-08-16 instead of 15 as the result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Hive INTERVAL to achieve this.

*select (max(datejour) - INTERVAL '6' DAY) as maxdate from table*

Above query should return **2015-08-15**

You can find more details - 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hive Date builtin function to achieve this

```
select date_sub('2015-08-22', 6) from table
```

Above query should return `2015-08-15`

You can find more Hive built-in function here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Hope his helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE_SUB function to get your requirement.
Query may look like this(in your case):

```
select DATE_SUB(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(MAX(t1.max_date) AS string) ,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 6) from (select MAX(datejour) as max_date from table) t1 group by t1.max_date;
```

Comment: Thx DRAGO, it works well. Could you have any idea on how I can make an 'UPDATE' on my table? this operation is available only on HIVE 0.14

Comment: shakile,can you raise a proper question for what type of update do you want,with some sample data input/output,so that i can provide you with better answer and query...

Comment: Drago, I added a post like answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since updating records using UPDATE command is not possible in hive and adding columns through alter command is not recommended as you have to insert values in it through same table.

```
create external table test(
  fields1 string,
  field2 string)

create external table test(
  fields1 string,
  field2 string,
  h01 string
  )

Insert overwrite table table2 
select 
fields1,
field2,
case when fields1 = '' then 'OK' else 'KO' end as h01 from table1 where your_condition;
```

Comment: Thx Drago. One more thing. It's possible use DATE_SUB() as sub-query. I'm trying to do : select * from tmp_ext_histo where datejour between (select max(datejour) from tmp_ext_histo) and (select max(datejour) from tmp_ext_histo) but I get this error : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:52 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification...why?

Comment: sub-queries are not supported in hive,so we use joins for it.If you want query to get data for specified period of time than please give me some data input/output sample and mostly date format and type and please do vote if answers are right.thnx

Comment: Hi Drago....your code works perfetly. And as you ask to me, I leave as a comment my need with more details. In fact, I'm looking for a Hive's translation of my postgresql code.Thx